# How to make automatic screen capture program for math question workbook

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, automation, screenshot, screen-capture

I want to make a auto screen capture program and the program recognize each questions' height and width and control the capturing size (like green box in example image).

Is the deep learning or AI technology essential?? I really want to make this program but I don't know what language should I study.

[Example Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSokj.png)

Comment: Have you checked in here for anything similar? Might give you a start…

Comment: Yes, I searched 'auto screen capture' programs but, I couldn't find any programs that recognize the specific format that I want to capture

Comment: Oh, you expect to find complete programs on here...

Comment: It would be good if I can find complete program but all I just to want to know is how to make that kind program. Outline guideline and insight of experts. what programming language can be used to make the program and  is AI, deep-learning tech is necessary to make this program.

Comment: So, have you listed the tasks that your program will have to do to have the features you want? That would be a first step.

Comment: Ok, Let me think about it more specific. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No you don't need deep learning. if you environment (where your images are placed, maybe it is full screen, or not) is controlled, you can leverage simple image processing techniques. If you don't have such knowledge, using a pre-trained object detection and object localization libraries (maybe using deep-learning) would be the next choice.